# getting a bump with git sub-module when creating a diff

Tags: git

I am contributing to  a project that has git sub-modules in the repo.I am running the latest commit (as per the project) in the sub-module
When I try to create a diff, I get a bump with the sub-module.

What could be wrong?

Even on a clean branch I get this

```
git diff 

diff --git a/asmjit b/asmjit
--- a/asmjit
+++ b/asmjit
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit a66efd54609aab7dd98e34c069937f34aa7c8f95
+Subproject commit a66efd54609aab7dd98e34c069937f34aa7c8f95-dirty
lines 1-6/6 (END)
```

Comment: How are you creating the diff?

Comment: I create the diff using git diff

Comment: And how do you see that "bump" in the submodule?

Comment: Take a look at the edit

Comment: Could you also know how I could get rid of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bump you see is not the result of a `diff`: a `git status` should report the same "dirty" state for the submodule.

To get rid of it, you need to go in the submodule folder, do a `git status` and identify what causes the state to be dirty.
It can be for instance some private (not tracked) files, automatically generated.